# Display different value other than x and y axis value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Need to display the different value on mouseover tooltip value other than x and y-axis value on highcharts.

Given data where I need to use `graphValue` to display on the chart and `actualValue` to display on the tooltip.

```
data = [
{'graphValue': 10, 'actualValue': 10 },
{'graphValue': 20, 'actualValue': 20 },
{'graphValue': 0, 'actualValue': -15 },
{'graphValue': 10, 'actualValue': 10 },
{'graphValue': 0, 'actualValue': -20 },
{'graphValue': 10, 'actualValue': 10 },
{'graphValue': 0, 'actualValue': -20 },
{'graphValue': 15, 'actualValue': 15 }
]
```

please let me know how to achieve this. Thank you.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/52jr6p9z/

Comment: @ewolden, thanks. I this may help

Comment: I created a fiddle for you. Good luck https://jsfiddle.net/byud9a6o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom point property to `tooltip` by `pointFormat` option:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.actualValue}</b><br/>'
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06jawfo1/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to give each data its own object like this

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
  console.log(this);
    return 'The real value is <b>'+ this.key+ '</b>';
  }
},

    series: [{
        name: 'a',
        data: [{name:10,y:20},20,{name:'-10',y:0},10,0,10,0,15]
    }]

});

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqw7vyuf/